# How to rescale a bayesnet figure

Tags: tikz-styles

I want to rescale a bayesnet tikz diagram. My document is actually multicolum and with two bayesnet diagrams fitted in one column, but I think the real problem is how to rescale this bayesnet diagram:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}


\begin{document}

  \tikz{
% nodes
 \node[obs] (x) {$x$};%
 \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=-1cm,path picture={\fill[gray!25] (path picture bounding box.south) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north west);}] 
(y) {$y$}; %
 \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=1cm] (z) {$z$}; %

% plate
 \plate [inner sep=.25cm,yshift=.2cm] {plate1} {(x)(y)(z)} {$N$}; %

% edges
 \edge {y,z} {x}  
    }

\end{document}
```

How can I make the whole diagram bigger/smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AndréC's answer already mentions that one should use `transform shape` in some way. However, I do not agree on the details. I propose to add an overall `transform shape` to the picture and then redefine one style.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,transform shape,wrap/.style={inner sep=0pt,
fit=#1,transform shape=false}]
% nodes
 \node[obs] (x) {$x$};%
 \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=-1cm,path picture={\fill[gray!25] (path picture bounding box.south) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north west);}] 
(y) {$y$}; %
 \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=1cm] (z) {$z$}; %

% plate
\plate[inner sep=.25cm,yshift=.2cm,transform shape=false]{plate1}{(x)(y)(z)}{$N$}; %

% edges
 \edge {y,z} {x}  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that this applies to your code. I did not extensively test other sample documents. In your code, you could achieve the same effect also by saying

```
\renewcommand{\plate}[4][]{ %
  \node[wrap=#3,transform shape=false] (#2-wrap) {}; %
  \node[plate caption=#2-wrap] (#2-caption) {#4}; %
  \node[plate=(#2-wrap)(#2-caption), #1,transform shape=false] (#2) {}; %
}
```

after

\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}

And, as you can see, I used the liberty to drop unnecessary packages and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

By default, nodes are not sensitive to enlargements and reductions. To do this, it is necessary to use the `transform shape` operation (see page 234 of TikZ's manual 3.0.1a).

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,every node/.style={transform shape}]
% nodes
 \node[obs] (x) {$x$};%
 \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=-1cm,path picture={\fill[gray!25] (path picture bounding box.south) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north west);}] 
(y) {$y$}; %
 \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=1cm] (z) {$z$}; %

% plate
 \plate [inner sep=.25cm,yshift=.2cm] {plate1} {(x)(y)(z)} {$N$}; %

% edges
 \edge {y,z} {x}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is something strange with the \plate behaviour, it makes the nodes to keep the same size as without the scale = 1.5 funtionallity. If I comment out the \plate line, the whole diagram scales accoringly.

Comment: This library is not documented. And `\plate`t is a node from the little documentation I found on CTAN. So its maintainer has made modifications that disrupt the normal functioning of TikZ.  The easiest way is to make this diagram in pure TikZ.

Comment: I have contacted the maintainer, lets see if he has any workaround.