# How to add self-loop to node in bayesnet?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Many questions have already asked how to add a loop to a finite state machine-like plot, but I can't find an answer specifically regarding `bayesnet`. Can someone tell me how to add a self-loop to a node in `bayesnet`?

Something like this: 
[how do I draw a self loop and also label graph edges in Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321312/how-do-i-draw-a-self-loop-and-also-label-graph-edges-in-tikz)

Edit: Added sample code. One problem is that the loop and the plate's bottom text don't both fit in the plate.

```
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \tikz{
        \node[latent] (b_t) {$b_t$} ;
        \node[latent, right=of b_t] (t_t)
        {$t_t$} ;
        \node[obs, right=of t_t] (o_t) {$o_t$} ;
        % \edge {b_t} {b_t} ;
        \edge {b_t} {t_t} ;
        \edge {t_t} {o_t} ;
        \path (b_t) edge [loop above] (b_t);
        \plate[inner sep=0.225cm, yshift=.25cm] {plate1} {(b_t) (t_t) (o_t) (b_t')} {T}; %
    }
    \end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! If you provide us with a sample code, you will get very quickly an answer. Otherwise you expect others to make up some code, and this can take long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loops work as usual. I just copied a [random example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467629) and added a loop.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[bend]}]
% nodes
 \node[obs] (x) {$x$};%
 \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=-1cm,path picture={\fill[gray!25] (path picture bounding box.south) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north west);}] 
(y) {$y$}; %
 \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=1cm] (z) {$z$}; %
 \path (z) edge [loop above] node (z') {$Z$} (z);

% plate
\plate[inner sep=.25cm,yshift=.2cm,transform shape=false]{plate1}{(x)(y)(z)(z')}{$N$}; %

% edges
 \edge {y,z} {x}  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: As for the code from your update: add an auxiliary coordinate for the fit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[latent] (b_t) {$b_t$} ;
        \node[latent, right=of b_t] (t_t)
        {$t_t$} ;
        \node[obs, right=of t_t] (o_t) {$o_t$} ;
        % \edge {b_t} {b_t} ;
        \edge {b_t} {t_t} ;
        \edge {t_t} {o_t} ;
        \path (b_t) edge [loop above] coordinate[midway](aux) (b_t);
        \plate[inner sep=0.225cm] {plate1}
         {(b_t) (t_t) (o_t) (aux)} {T}; %
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Adding an auxiliary coordinate.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=pft]
        \node[latent] (b_t) {$b_t$} ;
        \node[latent, right=of b_t] (t_t)
        {$t_t$} ;
        \node[obs, right=of t_t] (o_t) {$o_t$} ;
        % \edge {b_t} {b_t} ;
        \edge {b_t} {t_t} ;
        \edge {t_t} {o_t} ;
        \path (b_t) edge [loop above] (b_t);
  \end{scope}       
  \plate[inner sep=0.225cm] {plate1} {(pft)} {T}; %
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Using a \texttt{local bounding box} node. (Note that this will probably improve
at a given point when the \texttt{bbox} library gets improved. Currently
development is frozen.)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you find the syntax for `\path`?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer I do not understand the question. This is all in the `pgfmanual`. `\path` is (sort of) the main command, and `\draw` is just a shorthand for `\path[draw]`, `\fill` for `\path[fill]` and so on (up to some subtleties which are not important here).

Comment: I'm confused by `z'`. What is this node? I'm currently running into the program that if I don't include your `Z`, my plate isn't large enough to include the loop and the plate value (e.g. N).

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer `z'` is just the name of the node of content `Z` that is above the loop. It is not really used here.

Comment: I updated my post with an example. Do you know how to expand the plate so that both the loop and the plate value both fit?

Comment: Oh, I can just increase `inner sep`

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer The IMHO cleaner way is to add an auxiliary coordinate, see the update. What I said above was not entirely correct. I *did* use `z'` for the fit, just forgot about it. Similarly you can add a coordinate at the outermost coordinate of the fit. (You could simplify everything by using a `local bounding box`, I guess.)